# asp.net - route and Culture

Tags: asp.net

I am currently translating words into languages ​​according to Localization. But I also want to disable the link. According to the language, I want to add language suffixes at the end like www .... / tr / eng / sp. How can I do this referral? Right now, the link only stays as www ... /, it doesn't add the language suffix to the end, so it doesn't redirect. What adjustment should I make?

**BaseController**

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void ExecuteCore()
        {
            int culture = 0;
            if (this.Session == null || this.Session["CurrentCulture"] == null)
            {

                int.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culture"], out culture);
                this.Session["CurrentCulture"] = culture;
            }
            else
            {
                culture = (int)this.Session["CurrentCulture"];
            }
            CultureHelper.CurrentCulture = culture;

            base.ExecuteCore();
        }

        protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

    }
```

**HomeController**

```
  public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult ChangeCurrentCulture(int id)
        { 
            CultureHelper.CurrentCulture = id;
            Session["CurrentCulture"] = id;
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**CultureHelper**

```
 public class CultureHelper
    {
        protected HttpSessionState session;

        //constructor   
        public CultureHelper(HttpSessionState httpSessionState)
        {
            session = httpSessionState;
        }
        public static int CurrentCulture
        {
            get
            {
                if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en-GB")
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "tr-TR")
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "mr-IN")
                {
                    return 2;
                }
                else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "ar-SA")
                {
                    return 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            set
            {

                if (value == 0)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                }
                else if (value == 1)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
                }
                else if (value == 2)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("mr-IN");
                }
                else if (value == 3)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                }

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

            }
        }
    }
```